# CSS class last-of-type child to another color

Tags: css

I have a problem with painting last element with class `.active` child `.progress-indicator` to different color.

This selector does not work properly: `.progress-step.active:last-of-type .progress-indicator`.

It selects last `.progress-step` (number 4) when it acquire class `.active`.

How can I do it in my case?

This is my CodepPen sample:
https://codepen.io/Liohich/pen/QWgqmRz

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `:last-of-type` does not work for selecting classes and is should instead be applied to an element type. You can achieve your desired styling with JavaScript.

In my solution, I have added the class `last` to the `.progress-indicator` that is clicked.

```css
.progress-step.active.last .progress-indicator {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```js
$('.progress-step').click(function() {
    $('.progress-step').removeClass('last');  
    $(this).toggleClass('last');
});
```